# Decomposing a matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra

In my book, there is an example in which one skips the step of computing the characteristic polynomial of $A$ in order to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$. In particular, they want to find all solutions to the equation

$$\dot{x} = Ax = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 \\ 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\ 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 5 \end{pmatrix}x, $$

and they skip the step described by observing that

$$Ax = A\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \end{pmatrix} = (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5)\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2\\ 3 \\ 4\\ 5\\ \end{pmatrix}. $$

I thought that this was pretty clever. Right now, I want to find the characteristic polynomial in order to find the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&6\\3&6&9&18\\5&10&15&30\\7&14&21&42 \end{pmatrix} $$

and I was wondering if something similar can be done since these are nice numbers.

The columns of a given row follow the pattern $x,2x,3x,6x$.

I have not been able to get anything.

Comment: Why does your vector $x$ have five components when $A$ has four columns?

Comment: Hey, I typed the wrong matrix for the first part. Please see my edit.

Comment: OK. Well, you know that your matrix (the $4\times 4$ one) has rank $1$. So its nullity is $3$. So there are at least three eigenvalues of $0$. You can find the last eigenvalue using the trace.

Comment: Yes, I did that. It has eigenvalue $64$